# Groovy Meta-Programming added method is not accessible in subclass

Tags: inheritance, groovy, metaprogramming

I have the following class to extends the Object class, but the the added method here cannot be accessible by any Object's subclasses.  Is there a workaround or that's Groovy meta-programming restriction / limitation?

```
package groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang;

class ObjectMetaClass extends DelegatingMetaClass {
    static {
        Object.metaClass.enableGlobally();
    }

    ObjectMetaClass(MetaClass meta) {
        super(meta);
        meta.enableGlobally();
    }

    Object invokeMethod(Object object,
                        String method,
                        Object[] arguments) {
        if (method == 'bar') {
            bar(*arguments);
        } else {
            super.invokeMethod object, method, arguments
        }
    }

    Object bar(config, app) {
        println("... ObjectMetaClass.bar(${config}, ${app})");
    }
}
```

**in testing script:**

```
o = new Object();
o.bar("profile.properties", "meta-app"); // works

1.bar("profile.properties", "integer-app"); // does not works
"aString".bar("profile.properties", "string-app"); // does not works
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got at least a couple of options: the [ExpandoMetaClass](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#metaprogramming_emc) and [Categories](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#categories).

## With the ExpandoMetaClass

```
Object.metaClass.bar = {config, app ->
    "... Object.bar(${config}, ${app})"
}

o = new Object();

assert o.bar("profile.properties", "meta-app") == '... Object.bar(profile.properties, meta-app)'
assert 1.bar("profile.properties", "integer-app") == '... Object.bar(profile.properties, integer-app)'
assert "aString".bar("profile.properties", "string-app") == '... Object.bar(profile.properties, string-app)'
```

## With a Category

```
class BarCategory {
    static Object bar(Object self, config, app) {
        "... Object.bar(${config}, ${app})"
    }
}

use(BarCategory) {
    o = new Object();

    assert o.bar("profile.properties", "meta-app") == '... Object.bar(profile.properties, meta-app)'
    assert 1.bar("profile.properties", "integer-app") == '... Object.bar(profile.properties, integer-app)'
    assert "aString".bar("profile.properties", "string-app") == '... Object.bar(profile.properties, string-app)'
}

o = new Object();

try {
    o.bar("profile.properties", "meta-app")
    assert false, 'You should not see this'
} catch (MissingMethodException) {}

try {
    1.bar("profile.properties", "integer-app")
    assert false, 'You should not see this'
} catch (MissingMethodException) {}

try {
   "aString".bar("profile.properties", "string-app")
    assert false, 'You should not see this'
} catch (MissingMethodException) {}
```

With a Category you can control the scope of the `bar()` method.

Comment: is there a way to place the Object.metaClass.bar = { .. } somewhere where it will automatically loaded  so it wouldn't need to appear in every scripts? Thanks!  Category is great way too, but I tried minimize the need to modified the existing scripts if all possible.  Again, thanks

Comment: Besides the class static initializer (which won't work in your case) I don't know how to automatically load the meta-programming. I believe there are two ways. One I could not find at the moment, but the other uses a Category that's automatically loaded: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_extension_modules